# Cannot find "stateless_validation.h" after calling CreateShaderModule() in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I have tried to setup Vulkan validation layers, and after running vulkaninfoSDK.exe indeed have multiple validation layers, but I get a message in VS Code "unable to open 'stateless_validation.h': Unable to read file 'c:\j\msdk\build\vulkan-validationlayers\repo\layers\stateless_validation.h".

This message is very strange to me, as I do not even have a folder "j" on my c drive, and have in fact installed Vulkan somewhere on a completely different drive. I am running Windows, the MSVC compiler, have installed the latest Vulkan SDK from LunarG, and have set the environment variable "VK_LAYER_PATH" as recommended here: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.131.1/windows/layer_configuration.html but indeed, the folder I have installed the SDK to does not contain a "stateless_validation.h".

My call stack is 3 functions in VkLayer_khronos_validation.dll: "StatelessValidation::validate_struct_pnext", then "StatelessValidation::PreCallValidateCreateShaderModule,", then "vulkan_layer_chassis::CreateShaderModule" called from my own function.

I notice the file "stateless_validation.h" is on the Github repo here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers but I would think downloading the SDK would be enough.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Then don't debug the layers. The warning simply says you do not have the source files, and would be shown assembly instead.

Comment: @krOoze I wasn't attempting to debug it, but your comment indeed helped me solve the issue, as answered below, so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error was an exception thrown inside the actual validation layer source code itself, and was due to the **pNext** member of my **VkShaderModuleCreateInfo** structure instance I was passing to **vkCreateShaderModule** being uninitialized.

Simply setting this to nullptr solved my issue. It seems that since the exception was thrown from inside the dll itself, my exception handling code was not catching it, which confused me.